# Adicionar uma função no Resource de rotas do Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

sou novo no Laravel, estou com uma dúvida, quero implementar uma função além do que já existe na parte de Resource.

No Resource ele fica assim

```
Route::resources([
    'users' => UserController::class,
    'placas' => PlacaController::class,
]);
```

Só que não quero usar o método Destroy, então criei um método Delete, mas para poder usar esse método, tive que optar por escrever mais linhas

```
Route::prefix('placas')->name('placas.')->group(function(){
    Route::get('', [PlacaController::class, 'index'])->name('index');
    Route::get('create', [PlacaController::class, 'create'])->name('create');
    Route::post('store', [PlacaController::class, 'store'])->name('store');
    Route::get('{placa}/edit', [PlacaController::class, 'edit'])->name('edit');
    Route::put('update/{placa}', [PlacaController::class, 'update'])->name('update');
    Route::post('/delete', [PlacaControlleroller::class, 'delete'])->name('delete');
});
```

Há alguma forma em que eu possa adicionar só o delete na parte de placas no Resource

Answer (score 0):

tudo bem?

Como você já deve saber, o Laravel resource router habilita um CRUD padrão, seguindo um modelo determinado pelos próprios desenvolvedores do Laravel. Por isso a opção de nomear o método como detroy() e não como delete() como você gostaria.

É possível você remover apenas o destroy() do CRUD, encadeando, ou o método `only()` ou o método `except()`. No teu caso, deve ficar mais ou menos assim:

```
Route::resources([
    'users' => UserController::class,
    'placas' => PlacaController::class,
])->except(['destroy']);
```

Isso é descrito [nesta parte da documentação](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/controllers#restful-partial-resource-routes).

Espero que isso te ajude!

Abraço!